# Question about parameter posterior in bayesian linear regression

Tags: bayesian

At page 4 of cs229 section note (http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/cs229-gaussian_processes.pdf), I don't understand eq(2)

[image: question]

In this equation,

- how do the $\theta$ is differentiated ? I think $\theta$ is just like that
  $
  \theta =  
      \begin{bmatrix}
      \theta^{(1)} \\
      \vdots \\
      \theta^{(n)} \\
      \end{bmatrix}
  $
  . $\theta^{'} = ? $
- How does the equation is equal ? $ p(S|\theta) = \prod^m_{i=1} p(y^{(i)} | x^{(i)}, \theta) $

  - $p(S) = \prod^m_{i=1} p(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)})$ right?

The more condition is like that.
[image: condition]

Comment: These notes seem too sparse to help nail down the concepts behind all the notation. I would go back over your notes or find alternative ones / book to understand this and intersperse this with examples.

Comment: Anyone who help me ?

Comment: it's difficult to help you as your question is essentially 'help me learn bayesian statistics'. I suggest going back to the lecture notes / alternative such as a book (not just a section note) and get the concepts. Broadly speaking the $\theta'$ is takes each of the possible values that $\theta$ can take so we condition on this.